# Where to put common resources in yii2 advanced?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to access my **css** and **javascript** files in both **frontend** and **backend**.

So, my question is where i put **css** and **javascript** files so they are **accessible** for both frontend and backend.

Or is there any way to **reuse** **files** i.e. i put my css file in **web** folder of **backend** and use it in **frontend**.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. You can re use it. But, to seek help you need to post your directory structure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it says [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html#$sourcePath-detail), you can make asset bundle in @common folder and set property $sourcePath, using an alias or absolute path to directory with your scripts and styles. The scripts directory may not be web-accessible.

Try something like this:

```
namespace common\assets;
use yii\web\AssetBundle;
/**
 * Main frontend application asset bundle.
 */
class CommonAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@common/scripts';
    public $css = [
    ];
    public $js = [
        'blabla.js'
    ];
    public $depends = [
    ];
}
```

And place your scripts to common/scripts. Also don't forget to register this asset in your layout or another view:

```
use common\assets\CommonAsset; 
CommonAsset::register($this);
```

Worked for me.